# Checking if value exists in array with array_search()

Tags: php

If `0` could be a possible key returned from `array_search()`, what would be the best method for testing if an element exists in an array using this function (or any php function; if there's a better one, please share)?

I was trying to do this:

```
if(array_search($needle, $haystack)) //...
```

But that would of course return `false` if `$needle` is the first element in the array. I guess what I'm asking is is there some trick I can do in this `if` statement to get it to behave like I want it? I tried doing these, but none of them worked:

```
$arr = array(3,4,5,6,7);

if(array_search(3, $arr) != false)  //...

if(array_search(3, $arr) >= 0)  //...
```

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an alternative to `===` and `!==`, you can also use `in_array`:

```
if (in_array($needle, $haystack))
```

Comment: Good alternative. The only cons is that to get the position you have to call another function.

Comment: Ah! That's what I was looking for :) Thx!

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa Don't need the key :)

Comment: No problems :) You should still look into @Aurelio's answer however. There are many places where it is necessary to use the `===` and `!==` operators. Understanding them is a requirement for any PHP developer.

Comment: I definitely did and glad for his answer! Just in this case, your answer is sufficient.

Answer (score 15):

This is the way:

```
if(array_search(3, $arr) !== false)
```

Note the use of the `===` PHP operator, called identical (not identical in this case). You can read more info in the [official doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). You need to use it because with the use of the equal operator you can't distinguish 0 from false (or null or '' as well).

A better solution if you find the match and want to use the integer value is:

```
if (($pos = array_search(3, $arr)) !== false)
{
   // do stuff using $pos
}
```

Comment: Holy crap. That was fastest answer of all time

Comment: @Shredder Glad you like it :p

Comment: First time I had to use this operator. yay

Comment: This is the better solutions, as it allows for the key to also be used following the check. Don't know why this isn't the accepted one

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `===`, `!==`, *and* `in_array()`, you can use `array_flip()`:

```
$arr = [3,4,5,6,7];

$rra = array_flip($arr);

if( $rra[3] !== null ):

  var_dump('Do something, '.$rra[3].' exists!');

endif;
```

This is not fewer lines than the accepted answer. But it does allow you to get position and existence in a very human-readable way.

We want to find out if int 3 is in `$arr`, the original array:

```
array (size=5)
0 => int 3
1 => int 4
2 => int 5
3 => int 6
4 => int 7
```

array_flip creates a new array (`$rra`) with swapped key-value pairs:

```
array (size=5)
3 => int 0
4 => int 1
5 => int 2
6 => int 3
7 => int 4
```

Now we can verify the existence of int 3, which will (or will not be) a key in `$rra` with `array_key_exists,` isset`, or by enclosing` $rra[3]` in an if statement.

Since the value we are looking for could have an array key id of `0`, we need to compare against `null` and not rely on evaluating `0` to `false`.

You can also make changes to the original array, should that be the use case, because if `$rra[3]` isn't `null`, `$rra[3]` will return what is the key (position `0`, in this case) for the value in the original array.

```
if ( $rra[3] !== null ):
  // evaluates to: unset( $array[0] );
  unset( $arr[ $rra[3] ] );
endif;
```

This operation works just as well if you're working with an associative array.